# 401 Error Bad Credentials in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot 3.1.5 application. I just implemented Spring Security into my application, but when I tried to login using default credentials, it always returned 401 error (Bad credentials) for any type of request (POST/PUT/DELETE/GET) I sent. I have a PostgreSQL data source, and I implemented the password as BCrypt type straight into the database. Does anyone have any ideas on why I get 401 error or any helpful references? Thank you.

[Response from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjWOm.png)

So here is my code:

My database sequel:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."user" (
    userid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    roles VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    fullname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

-- Inserting data into the "user" table
INSERT INTO public."user" (userid, username, password, email, roles, fullname)
VALUES
    (1, 'john', '$2a$12$A0/jY7NwmY4YTmqPHA0vSuJrhSY.k45sQR34XhEDMgxFJVSgc04tW', 'john@test.com', 'admin user', 'John Doe'),
    (2, 'eric', '$2a$12$AGmHEKS6hYzRMVdH0edkReu6OMbgI.F4gO1ENWrUr2/C7p5eMkN6y', 'eric@test.com', 'user', 'Eric Smith'),
    (3, 'tom', '$2a$12$wOAnqh7frKwARxYsRNS1wO9slB5fNGTsMclkhuzxg6Fv/YcOrgZWa', 'tom@test.com', 'user', 'Tom Johnson');
```

User.java:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "user",schema = "public")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "userid")
    private Integer userid;

    @Column(name = "username")
    @NotEmpty(message = "username is required.")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @NotEmpty(message = "password is required.")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email")
    @NotEmpty(message = "email is required.")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "roles")
    @NotEmpty(message = "roles are required.")
    private String roles; // Space separated string

    @Column(name = "fullname")
    @NotEmpty(message = "fullname is required.")
    private String fullname; // Space separated string

    public User() {
    }
}
```

User Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    private final UserService userService;
    private final UserDtoToUserConverter userDtoToUserConverter; // Convert userDto to user.

    private final UserToUserDtoConverter userToUserDtoConverter; // Convert user to userDto.


    public UserController(UserService userService, UserDtoToUserConverter userDtoToUserConverter, UserToUserDtoConverter userToUserDtoConverter) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.userDtoToUserConverter = userDtoToUserConverter;
        this.userToUserDtoConverter = userToUserDtoConverter;
    }
    @GetMapping
    public Result findAllUsers() {
        List<User> foundUsers = this.userService.findAll();

        // Convert foundUsers to a list of UserDtos.
        List<UserDto> userDtos = foundUsers.stream()
                .map(this.userToUserDtoConverter::convert)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Note that UserDto does not contain password field.
        return new Result(true, StatusCode.SUCCESS, "Find All Success", userDtos);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{userid}")
    public Result findUserById(@PathVariable Integer userid) {
        User foundUser = this.userService.findById(userid);
        UserDto userDto = this.userToUserDtoConverter.convert(foundUser);
        return new Result(true, StatusCode.SUCCESS, "Find One Success", userDto);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Result addUser(@Valid @RequestBody User newuser) {
        User savedUser = this.userService.save(newuser);
        UserDto savedUserDto = this.userToUserDtoConverter.convert(savedUser);
        return new Result(true, StatusCode.SUCCESS, "Add Success", savedUserDto);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{userid}")
    public Result updateUser(@PathVariable Integer userid, @Valid @RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        User update = this.userDtoToUserConverter.convert(userDto);
        User updatedUser = this.userService.update(userid, update);
        UserDto updatedUserDto = this.userToUserDtoConverter.convert(updatedUser);
        return new Result(true, StatusCode.SUCCESS, "Update Success", updatedUserDto);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{userid}")
    public Result deleteUser(@PathVariable Integer userid) {
        this.userService.delete(userid);
        return new Result(true, StatusCode.SUCCESS, "Delete Success");
    }
}
```

UserService.java

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService    {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;



    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    public List<User> findAll() {
        return this.userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public User findById(Integer userid) {
        return this.userRepository.findById(userid)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ObjectNotFoundException("user", userid));
    }

    public User save(User newUser) {
        // We NEED to encode plain password before saving to the DB! TODO
        newUser.setPassword(this.passwordEncoder.encode(newUser.getPassword()));
        return this.userRepository.save(newUser);
    }

    public User update(Integer userid, User update) {
        User oldUser = this.userRepository.findById(userid)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ObjectNotFoundException("user", userid));
        oldUser.setUsername(update.getUsername());
        oldUser.setFullname(update.getFullname());
        oldUser.setRoles(update.getRoles());
        return this.userRepository.save(oldUser);
    }

    public void delete(Integer userid) {
        this.userRepository.findById(userid)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ObjectNotFoundException("user", userid));
        this.userRepository.deleteById(userid);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return this.userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                .map(user -> {
                    MyUserPrincipal myUserPrincipal = new MyUserPrincipal(user);
                    // Log to check password got from MyUserPrincipal
                    System.out.println("myUserPrincipal password: "+myUserPrincipal.getPassword());
                    return myUserPrincipal;
                })
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("username " + username + " is not found."));
    }
}
```

MyUserPrincipal

```
public class MyUserPrincipal implements UserDetails {



    private User user;
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    public MyUserPrincipal(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        this.authorities = Arrays.stream(StringUtils.tokenizeToStringArray(this.user.getRoles(), " "))
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role))
                .toList();

        // Log the authorities
        System.out.println("Authorities: " + this.authorities);
    }


    // This is the method that is called when we want to get the authorities of the user
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        String[] roles = StringUtils.tokenizeToStringArray(this.user.getRoles(), " ");
        System.out.println("Tokenized Roles: " + Arrays.toString(roles));

        return Arrays.stream(roles)
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role))
                .toList();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(){
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

WebConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint;



    public SecurityConfiguration(CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint, CustomBearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint customBearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint, CustomBearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler customBearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler) {
        this.customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint = customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    }


    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeHttpRequests -> authorizeHttpRequests
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/users/**").authenticated() // Protect the endpoint.
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,  "/users").hasAuthority("ROLE_admin") // Protect the endpoint.
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/users/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_admin") // Protect the endpoint.
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,  "/users/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_user") // Protect the endpoint.
                        // Disallow everything else.
                        .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/actuator")).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .httpBasic(httpBasic -> httpBasic.authenticationEntryPoint(this.customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement ->
                        sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .build();
    }
}
```

CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint:

```
@Component
public class CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private final HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;

    public CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint(@Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver") HandlerExceptionResolver resolver) {
        this.resolver = resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.addHeader("WWW-Authenicate", "Basic realm=\"Realm\"");
        this.resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, authException)2;
    }
```

Here is stack trace when I sent request to Postman:

```
************************************************************

Request received for GET '/users/2':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@797f85f8

servletPath:/users/2
pathInfo:null
headers: 
authorization: Basic am9objokMmEkMTIkQTAvalk3TndtWTRZVG1xUEhBMHZTdUpyaFNZLms0NXNRUjM0WGhFRE1neEZKVlNnYzA0dFc=
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.35.0
accept: */*
postman-token: 843acd44-ee4d-459b-9f95-50b25fbf4032
host: localhost:8080
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
connection: keep-alive


Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CorsFilter
  LogoutFilter
  BasicAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]


************************************************************


Authorities: [ROLE_admin, ROLE_user]
myUserPrincipal password: $2a$12$A0/jY7NwmY4YTmqPHA0vSuJrhSY.k45sQR34XhEDMgxFJVSgc04tW
2023-11-21T20:37:13.391-06:00 ERROR 13532 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] e.t.c.m.s.e.ExceptionHandlerAdvice       : Authentication failed: username or password is incorrect.

org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:89) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:147) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ObservationAuthenticationManager.lambda$authenticate$1(ObservationAuthenticationManager.java:54) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.lambda$observe$4(Observation.java:544) ~[micrometer-observation-1.11.5.jar:1.11.5]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observeWithContext(Observation.java:603) ~[micrometer-observation-1.11.5.jar:1.11.5]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:544) ~[micrometer-observation-1.11.5.jar:1.11.5]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ObservationAuthenticationManager.authenticate(ObservationAuthenticationManager.java:53) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:174) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:323) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:224) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:78) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:67) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the wrong password with Postman. If I decode your base64 credentials, I get:

```
john:$2a$12$A0/jY7NwmY4YTmqPHA0vSuJrhSY.k45sQR34XhEDMgxFJVSgc04tW
```

This means that you're sending the Bcrypt hashed password in stead of the normal password.

Comment: No, I use an online BCrypt password generator and implement values in the database. In my SQL code, the password I inserted is not hashed yet.

Comment: @calmy_tt The online bcrypt password generator IS the hashing mechanism. Whatever you inserted in the database is already hashed with bcrypt. Whatever password you typed into the online bcrypt password generator is what you should send in Postman. For example, let's say my password is `password123`, then the result of the bcrypt password generator could be `$2a$12$fcuwIcEsDfWoZIZh7RHOLOVqrlBSy2fI2KDK3k4/Pd.GyXx1OREta`. That's what I add to my database, but in Postman I should send `password123`.

Comment: And this is regardless of what hashing mechanism you use. You should **never** send the same thing with Postman as what's in your database. And in your case you're doing exactly that.

Comment: Wow this works magically. Thank you so much for spotting this out. I cant believe I spent a whole week on this bug.